# Updating mat-calendar date css on an event

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to update the css of specific dates in mat calendar, when the user clicks on a button. This is the code I have:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCalendarCellClassFunction } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {
  dateClass1: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (cellDate, view) => {
    return '';
  };

  save() {
    this.dateClass1 = (cellDate: any, view: any) => {
      const date = cellDate.getDate();
      if (date === 10) {
        return 'start';
      }
      return '';
    };
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div style="width:300px">
<mat-card class="demo-inline-calendar-card">
  <mat-calendar  [dateClass]="dateClass1"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
<button (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

app.component.css:

```
button.start {
  border :2px solid  orange;
}
```

I am able to apply the css class, but the problem is, the class gets applied only when I change the current month or trigger some kind of change on the calendar. You can see below that even after clicking on save, the css is not applied. It gets applied only after triggering month change on the calendar manually.
[image]

My guess is that the Angular change detection is not firing when I click on the save button and hence not updating the UI. Its updating the UI only when I manually trigger an event on the calendar, like switching the current month.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the idea of @Eliseo response, I used this approach for a similar situation I had:

app.component.html:

```
<div style="width:300px">
    <mat-card class="demo-inline-calendar-card">
      <mat-calendar #calendar [dateClass]="dateClass" [dateClass]="dateClass" [(selected)]="selectedCalendarDate" (selectedChange)="onSelectedDateChanged()"></mat-calendar>
    </mat-card>
    <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild(MatCalendar, {static: false}) calendar!: MatCalendar<Date>;
selectedCalendarDate: Date | null = new Date();

dateClass: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (cellDate, view) => {
    if (view === 'month') { // Only highligh dates inside the month view.
        return cellDate === this.selectedCalendarDate ? 'start' : '';
    }
    return '';
};

onSelectedDateChanged() {
    if (this.calendar) {
        this.calendar.monthView._init(); // to refresh the calendar
    }
}
```

Basically it's grabbing the calendar instance with `ViewChild` and when a date is selected on the calendar it triggers a refresh of the calendar UI with `.init()`

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sakeness of completeness. One could use as well the `updateTodaysDate` function which will result in a rendering of the active  calender date.

```
@ViewChild(MatCalendar) calendar!: MatCalendar<Date>;
selectedDay(selDate: Date | null) {
  ...
  this.calendar.updateTodaysDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, by default the mat-calendar component does not reactively re-evaluate the CSS classes applied by the dateClass function when the function itself changes. The calendar is waiting for some kind of interaction to update.

One way to force an update on the calendar after you modify the dateClass function is to trigger change detection manually.

Here's how you can do it:

- First, inject ChangeDetectorRef in your component.
- After updating your dateClass1 function in the save method, trigger change detection manually using detectChanges.

Here's your updated app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCalendarCellClassFunction } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {
  dateClass1: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (cellDate, view) => {
    return '';
  };

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  save() {
    this.dateClass1 = (cellDate: any, view: any) => {
      const date = cellDate.getDate();
      if (date === 10) {
        return 'start';
      }
      return '';
    };
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Additionally, I noticed that your CSS is trying to apply styles to a button with a class of .start. This seems incorrect. Instead, you should be targeting the calendar cell directly. Update your app.component.css to:

```
mat-calendar-cell.start {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the HOST-X code not work

Instead of change the function "dateClass1", I would prefer use an auxiliar variable

```
  toogle: boolean = false;
  dateClass1: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (cellDate, view) => {
    if (this.toogle) {
      const date = cellDate.getDate();
      if (date === 10) {
        return 'start';
      }
    }
    return '';
  };
```

In your html use a button pass as argument the mat-calendar using a template reference variable

```
<mat-calendar #calendar [dateClass]="dateClass1" [(selected)]="date">
</mat-calendar>
<button (click)="click(calendar)">toogle</button>
```

the click function you can

```
  click(calendar: MatCalendar<any>) {
    this.toogle = !this.toogle;  //<--change the variable
    const cal: any = calendar.monthView;  //<--get the "monthView" of the calendar
    cal._createWeekCells();    //<--call to the function _createWeekCells
    cal._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();  //<--and say to the changeDetectorRef 
                                             //that detect changes
  }
```

You can see in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-td2g2v-puczar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-custom-header-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-custom-header-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts)

Comment: The code block in the other answer is character-for-character the same as I got when running this question through ChatGPT.  It would be nice if you could document the problems with that answer (perhaps via Flag) to help ensure it's handled appropriately.

Comment: The problem of the other block it's that **not** work (I tried it and don't work for me). For my answer, I go through the code of [mat-calendar](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts), then I see that you can access to the MatMonthView (it's a ViewChild), go to [class MatMonthView code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/datepicker/month-view.ts#L69) and in this MatMonthView you have a method that change the "_weeks" (this property is passed to a MatCalendarBody using an Input) and have a property _changeDetectorRef.