# mat-calendar not adding class with dateClass

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

so this is my Calendar:

```
  <div class="calendarWrapper mat-elevation-z1">
    <mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass"></mat-calendar>
  </div>
```

This is the scss for the class to be added:

```
button.orange {
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

And this is the TypeScript File for the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCalendarCellClassFunction } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import { ColorService } from 'src/app/_services/color.service';
import { AppointmentsDTO } from 'src/app/api/models';
import { WebsiteAppointmentsService } from 'src/app/api/services';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'bookings-element',
  templateUrl: './bookings-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bookings-element.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class BookingsElementComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedDate: string = '';

  appointments: AppointmentsDTO[] = [];

  constructor(
    public colorService: ColorService,
    private appointmentsService: WebsiteAppointmentsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  async getBookings() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      this.appointmentsService
        .getApiWebsiteAppointmentsGetAppointments({
          date: this.selectedDate,
          tenantid: environment.tenantId,
        })
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          if (data) {
            this.appointments = data;
            resolve();
            console.log(this.appointments);
          }
        });
    });
  }

  // dateClass: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = async (cellDate, view) => {
  //   if (view === 'month') {
  //     const cellISODate = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(cellDate), {
  //       zone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  //     }).toISODate();
  //     this.selectedDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(cellISODate), {
  //       zone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  //     }).toISODate();

  //     await this.getBookings();

  //     console.log('Selected Date:', cellISODate);
  //     console.log('Appointments:', this.appointments);

  //     const isBooked = this.appointments.some((appointment) => {
  //       const startDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(appointment.startDate), {
  //         zone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  //       }).toISODate();
  //       const endDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(appointment.endDate), {
  //         zone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  //       }).toISODate();

  //       console.log('Appointment Start Date:', startDate);
  //       console.log('Appointment End Date:', endDate);

  //       return (
  //         DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(cellISODate), {
  //           zone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  //         }) >=
  //           DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(startDate), {
  //             zone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  //           }) &&
  //         DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(cellISODate), {
  //           zone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  //         }) <=
  //           DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(endDate), {
  //             zone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  //           })
  //       );
  //     });

  //     console.log('isBooked:', isBooked);

  //     return isBooked ? 'orange' : '';
  //   }

  //   return '';
  // };

  dateClass: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (cellDate, view) => {
    // Only highligh dates inside the month view.
    if (view === 'month') {
      const date = cellDate.getDate();

      // Highlight the 1st and 20th day of each month.
      return date === 1 || date === 20 ? 'orange' : '';
    }

    return '';
  };
}
```

The problem is with the original dateClass function from Angular Material everythin is working fine and the class is being added. But with my custom dateClass function it won't work! The logic of it is working like expected, but the class isn't added to the buttons.
Anyone has an idea why it isn't adding the class? Maybe it's because of the async, but I need it for waiting for the API response.

Encapsulation isn't the problem, like u can see in my TS-File.
I expect the class 'orange' being added to the buttons, when isBooked from the dateClass function, which is commented right now, returns true.

Comment: Your assumption about async it true. If you look at the source code of the `MatMonthView` [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/e2ba68acc279a8b077eaecb189eb574d3c9b8bc3/src/material/datepicker/month-view.ts#L531) you'll notice it doesn't await on the function, so it will return without before the promise is resolved.

Comment: @TotallyNewb Yeah ur right. Do u have any idea how to avoid that? I don't get it.

Comment: You can't. The `dateClass` needs to be synchronous. Not sure what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to say more. Perhaps run the async part (i.e. `getBookings()`) after the value of the picker changes, and lock the UI in some way until it's resolved. Note that what you're currently doing, even if it worked, would make a request each time the `dateClass` is called, which is probably not what you want anyway.

Comment: I've created an answer based on my comment, including stackblitz example.

Comment: IT's a bit old, so the class prety sure are changed, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510066/how-can-i-catch-the-material-datepicker-month-pagination-event/60297741#60297741

Comment: Another it's when change the month call to the api, when the api is called "repaint" the calendar, like this another SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864849/updating-mat-calendar-date-css-on-an-event/76866605#76866605

Comment: @TotallyNewb Ah okay, I didn’t know that. Unfortunately my logic doesn’t work for me asynchronously. Thanks for ur effort all. I already changed the mat-calendar to this one: https://mattlewis-github.com/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink and it works fine for me:)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, the `dateClass` needs to be synchronous, since it's not awaited internally in `DatePicker` (see code [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/e2ba68acc279a8b077eaecb189eb574d3c9b8bc3/src/material/datepicker/month-view.ts#L531).

Since in your case the `dateClass` depends on the data which is set inside `getBookings` method, which on the other hand seems to depend on the currently selected date, you can move the logic around.

Run your `getBookings` method when value of the input changes, and lock UI until the response is there. Then use the logic you already have at hand.

I've prepared a sample stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sqhjcy).

EDIT: Just noticed your question relies on `mat-calendar` instead of `mat-date-picker`. Still, the same logic should be applicable.

EDIT2: Found a second to prepare stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dte5ke) for mat-calendar.